# Does restriction to an open subgroup preserve projective smooth representations?

Tags: nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory, p-adic-groups

Let $G$ be a locally profinite group and $K \le G$ an open subgroup. Does the restriction functor $\mathrm{Res}^G_K$ from the category of smooth $\mathbb{C}$-linear representations of $G$ to smooth $\mathbb{C}$-linear representations of $K$ preserve projective objects?

One is tempted to make an argument using the right adjoint $\mathrm{Ind}_K^G$, right exactness of which would suffice. But does the openness of $K$ imply the right exactness of the induction functor $\mathrm{Ind}_K^G$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The induction functor is actually exact, not just right-exact, so yes, you can do this. Seeing as you've essentially asked two questions about the induction functors on these groups, you might want to take a look at Bushnell--Henniart's *Local Langlands for GL2*; section 2 of this gives a pretty simple introduction to the two functors and their basic properties.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that this was in Bushnell-Henniart. Inspecting the proof there, I see that my assumptions were too restrictive: the same conclusion holds even if $K$ is merely closed (instead of being open) and with $\mathbb{C}$ replaced by any commutative ring $R$ such that $G$ has a compact open subgroup with pro-order in $R^*$.